# Flicker at top of recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can see a flicker within my recycler view right at the top. The flicker seems to resemble the top lines of my drawable shapes in the recycler view item.xml. I have made various adjustments to lines and other things to see if I could prevent the flicker but nothing appears to be working.

Here is my code;

**Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ScoreHistory">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_history_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/GameHistory_Title"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/lime"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RV_scorehistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_history_title" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rv_lines"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_ID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_ID" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/score_text"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_SCORE"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_SCORE"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/questions_text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_SCORE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_SCORE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/target_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I set background resources here in my adapter

```
class ScoreHistoryAdaptor : ListAdapter<SavedScores, ScoreHistoryAdaptor.SavedScoreViewHolder>(WordsComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SavedScoreViewHolder {
        return SavedScoreViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SavedScoreViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current.id,current.difficulty,current.sumtype,current.questioncount,current.answeredcorrectly)
    }

    class SavedScoreViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val IDItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_RV_ID)
        private val DiffultyItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_RV_DIFFICULTY)
        private val SumTypeItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_RV_SUMTYPE)
        private val qCountItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_RV_QCOUNT)
        private val ScoreItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_RV_SCORE)
        private var DIFFCODE = ""
        private var SUMTYPECODE = ""
        val myContext = SumTypeItemView.context
        fun bind(ID: Int?,DIFFICULTY:String?,SUMTYPE:String?,QC:Int?,SCORE:Int?) {
            IDItemView.text = ID.toString()
            when (DIFFICULTY) {
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.diffLVL1) -> {DIFFCODE = DIFFICULTY; DiffultyItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diff_easy_icon)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.diffLVL2) -> {DIFFCODE = DIFFICULTY ; DiffultyItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diff_normal_icon)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.diffLVL3) -> {DIFFCODE = DIFFICULTY; DiffultyItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diff_hard_icon) }
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.diffLVL4) -> {DIFFCODE = DIFFICULTY ; DiffultyItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diff_impossible_icon)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.random) -> {DIFFCODE = DIFFICULTY ; DiffultyItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diff_random_icon)}
            }

            DiffultyItemView.text = DIFFCODE
            when (SUMTYPE) {
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catMulti) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.multi_symbol) }
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catAdd) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.add_symbol)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catSub) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.sub_symbol)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catDiv) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.div_symbol)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catSqrR) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.sqr_symbol) + "n"}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catSqrD) -> {SUMTYPECODE = "n" + myContext.resources.getString(R.string.sqrd_symbol)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catCubeR) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.cuber_symbol) + "n"}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.catCubeD) -> {SUMTYPECODE = "n" + myContext.resources.getString(R.string.cubed_symbol)}
                myContext.resources.getString(R.string.random) -> {SUMTYPECODE = myContext.resources.getString(R.string.random)}
            }
            when (IsScoreLessThanTarget(SCORE!!.toInt(),QC!!.toInt())){
                true ->{ScoreItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.somewrong_icon)}
                false ->{ScoreItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.allcorrect_icon)}
            }
            SumTypeItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sumtype_icon)
            SumTypeItemView.text = SUMTYPECODE
            qCountItemView.text = QC.toString()
            ScoreItemView.text = SCORE.toString()
        }



        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): SavedScoreViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false)
                return SavedScoreViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class WordsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SavedScores>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SavedScores, newItem: SavedScores): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SavedScores, newItem: SavedScores): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
private fun IsScoreLessThanTarget(score:Int,target:Int): Boolean{
    return score < target
}
```

[image]

In another view using scrollview I get the same

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of what you are seeing!

Comment: @Harsh0021 added picture. And when you scroll its a flicker and as I stated above it resembles the top of the drawables from the items

Comment: What did you mean bu flicker. Can you please brief me about it?

Comment: @Harsh0021 it means it as you scroll it the lines you can see out of place flicker. Appear and disappear rapidly. Like a flicker. I cant describe it any better because flicker is the word used to describe it :/ and its not by scrolling fast necessarily. I can scroll just a millimetre at a time and it flickers still

Comment: Locate where you are taking at.

Comment: @Harsh0021 at the top of the recycler view below where it says History. The partial lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226309/discussion-between-harsh0021-and-unknownerror).

Comment: Did you try it other phones and is it a emultaor on you are testing?

Comment: @Harsh0021 I only have one physical device to test it on which is what I am using. Not used emulator

Comment: try using other devices. Maybe its problem of your phone or something else

Comment: @Harsh0021 I will assume it is device specific as I managed to test on two different Samsung devices and could not replicate the issue. But on my Hafury (don't say it....) it still happens. Wish I could figure the reason still...I am sure other people have rubbish devices like me lol

Comment: then make a tick and bounty

Comment: @Harsh0021 I don't consider this solved. The issue still exists on my device and possibly for many more that I have not been able to test. But as you have made the effort to engage with me on this I will tick yours if you include the comments I made in my answer (not solved but device specific). And if you want to take a look... I have help needed here too: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253777/monitor-room-repository-for-livedata-changes-and-update-views

Comment: @Harsh0021 Bounty can be awarded in 7 hours apparently

Comment: Try giving some padding to the recycler view on top

Comment: @Prashant.J can you post your comment as an answer please. Both my scrollview and recyclerview with 5dp padding top and bottom has prevent all flickering

Comment: You are doing lot of work in your onBind, loading backgrounds and setting them on views, and some of them are not necessary,
for example you have to move SumTypeItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sumtype_icon) out of your bind function

Comment: The more I look at your code more performance issues I see in it, you use resources from R.string with a when, which I believe has performance overhead on your recycler.

Comment: I've a suggestion for you, comment all lines in bind func, set your backgrounds in your My_item.xml for your textViews, run your code and check the result, tell me if you still see the flicker or not.

Comment: also post your SavedScores , then I may be able to check your data class and improve it somehow.

Comment: @feridok how do you set variable backgrounds directly within the xml layout file? I will add my data class. Just to advise as per comment from Prashant padding corrected my issue. And as a beginner I don't doubt there can be many improvements. As you suggest helping me with the data side please see this post instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253777/monitor-room-repository-for-livedata-changes-and-update-views

Comment: not variable, set a fixed one to check if lag/flicker is caused by bind logic or not.

Comment: @fedirok I am not convinced it was simply the adaptor as I have a scrollview where it also happens and this doesnt go through the adaptor. Further to this, the padding at top and bottom of either recyclerview or scrollview did solve the issue which I have confirmed. I am not denying the possibility still of setting so many resources being a cause of the issue in either location. My app does need to provide different visual appearances depending on the values being provided so I still need to be able to achieve that result.

Comment: @UnknownError I believe this is something only you can fix. There are a lot of moving parts so you have to minimize the problem as much as possible. Comment  out major parts of code to experiment with only one type of view. Try using match_parent instead of wrap_content for the root constraintlayout. Reduce data so that recyclerview scrolls just a little bit. Try LinearLayout instead of constraint, Try constraint with chain attribute. Basically divide and conquer.

Also some TextViews have different textAlignment. 

Personally I suspect, that issue is with layout height.

Comment: @nkhar please see all previous comments. I have stated a few times now that prashant comment gave the correct outcome. Text alignment is coming at as expected across large and small screens in both portrait and horizontal. I posted a link above to another post surrounding data and views. If you wish to review that it would be helpful as that post aims to try and reduce views and number of individual data points. Reducing data isnt the answer (IT NEVER SHOULD BE) but help refining the way data is accessed and displayed would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is arising because in your `my_item.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp" <---- Fixed Height
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#ae7f9c"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

and in your textviews like this one,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_ID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  <------ this hiding the background try using wrap_content
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

To solve this,

- Try not giving a fixed height from `my_item.xml` container, use `wrap_content`
- Add padding to the container `constaintlayout`
- add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your text views and `center_vertical` them,

then your issue will resolve, hope this helps

try not giving a fixed height to the container